# add react to a website : how import external node module?

Tags: reactjs, npm

from this ressource https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html I have integrate into my static website a basic component

```
<body>
  <div id="like_button_container"></div>

  <!-- Load React. -->
  <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-content-loader@3.4.1/dist/react-content-loader.min.js" crossorigin></script>

  <!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script src="like_button.js"></script>    
</body>    
</html>
```

like_button.js :

```
'use strict';

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ liked: true }) }>
          Like
        </button>
        <Facebook /> ???????????
      </div>
    );
  }
}

let domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />, domContainer);
```

How to use in this component an external module like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-content-loader ?

I tried to add script https://unpkg.com/react-content-loader@3.4.1/dist/react-content-loader.min.js into html page with import satement in my component but I have an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Facebook is not defined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never tried the code in [Add React to a Website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) chapter of the React documentation. It was a good time to tinker with it.

There are more than one potential problem with your attached code. You do not load Babel in your index.html. At least in the question. So you could not use jsx syntax in the like_button.js.

The second one is that you could not use import here. You have to find what is the namespace of the package. I logged out the window object, checked that and it is ContentLoader.

The rest is easy I created a standalone index.html with babel:
https://codesandbox.io/s/w27pjmq355

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Hello React!</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-content-loader@3.4.1/dist/react-content-loader.min.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
      console.log('window', window);
      class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>Hello world!</h1>
              <ContentLoader.Facebook />
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think you could try out React this way, but Babel usage is not recommended like this in production. I strongly recommend to install node and use create-react-app. This way you can use the whole toolchain in no time.

Or event create a new React sandbox on CodeSandbox.io

Comment: for Babel on dev I launch command "npx babel --watch src --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod". Thanks for example, Where have you find the good example <ContentLoader.Facebook /> ? I was wrong in putting <ContentLoader />

Comment: Where have you find the good example <ContentLoader.Facebook /> ?

Comment: I did net find an example. I find the ContentLoader name in the window object. I logged it out in my example code. You can see it yourself in the log.